# Python to check rpm is greater version

Tags: python, python-2.7, rpm

Could any one help me to check in Linux to meet rpm version

Below command I used to get package version.

```
  rpm -qi libstdc++6 | awk -F': ' '/Version/ {print $2}'
```

using sub-process, I get below out put

```
 6.2.1+r239768
```

Now I want to compare `6.2.1+r239768` is greater than  `5.1.1`

Below is results I am expected

```
output = 6.2.1+r239768
print "This rpm version is supported" 
output = 6.3+r23
print "This rpm version is supported"
output = 7.1.1+r57678
print "This rpm version is supported"
output = 5.1.1+r23677
print "This rpm version is not supported"
output = 4.1+r56888
print "This rpm version is not supported"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pkg_resources` module which you should already have as it is part of `setuptools`:

```
In []:
from pkg_resources import parse_version
parse_version('6.2.1+r239768') > parse_version('5.1.1')

Out[]:
True
```

So to get your output:

```
In []:
versions = ['6.2.1+r239768', '6.3+r23', '7.1.1+r57678', '5.1.1+r23677', '4.1+r56888']
base = parse_version('6.2.1+r239768')
for v in versions:
    print("Output = {}".format(v))
    print("This rpm version is {}supported".format('not ' if parse_version(v) < base else ''))

Out[]:
Output = 6.2.1+r239768
This rpm version is supported
Output = 6.3+r23
This rpm version is supported
Output = 7.1.1+r57678
This rpm version is supported
Output = 5.1.1+r23677
This rpm version is not supported
Output = 4.1+r56888
This rpm version is not supported
```

Comment: Is there way to achieve same without importing  parse_version. Few of the machines does not have this module

Comment: So you must have older version of Python, because these come default with `Py2.7.9+` and `Py3.4+`. You could look at the code for `pkg_resource`. Or you could just install the `pip` package - `yum install python-pip`.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 but thing is we cannot install module and upgrade python newer version. We have to use default modules and python2.7

Comment: shall i use source code pkg_resources? is that legal

Comment: The author asked for comparing RPM versions, which have different rules to python package versions. (Quite different, in fact.)

Answer (score 1):

I feels like you should be better of using the [python API for rpm](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-rpm-programming-python.html).

As I did not have RPM based system on hand right now, could not come up with code.

Following code, [taken from Section 16.5](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch16s05.html), can be adapted accordingly

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Reads in package header, compares to installed package.
# Usage:
# python vercompare.py libstdc++6.rpm
#
import os
import sys

import rpm
def readRpmHeader(ts, filename):
    """ Read an rpm header. """
    fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY)
    try:
        h = ts.hdrFromFdno(fd)
    finally:
        os.close(fd)
    return h

ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
h = readRpmHeader( ts, sys.argv[1] )
pkg_ds = h.dsOfHeader()
for inst_h in ts.dbMatch('name', h['name']):
    inst_ds = inst_h.dsOfHeader()
    if pkg_ds.EVR() >= inst_ds.EVR():
        print "Package file is same or newer, OK to upgrade."
    else:
        print "Package file is older than installed version."
```

Answer (score 1):

`$ rpmdev-vercmp 6.2.1+r239768 6.3+r23
6.2.1+r239768 < 6.3+r23`

You can read the exit code:

`rpmdev-vercmp <EVR1> <EVR2>`

Exit status is 0 if the EVR's are equal, 11 if EVR1 is newer, and 12 if EVR2
is newer.  Other exit statuses indicate problems.

Answer (score 0):

The python rpm library gives you a way to compare a EVR (Epoch, Version, Release), but doesn't seem to give you the code to split a string into those parts. It's trivial, though. Here's a little working program.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import re
import sys

import rpm

evr_re = re.compile(r'^(?:([^:]*):)?([^-]+)(?:-(.*))?$')


def str_to_evr(s):
    mo = evr_re.match(s)
    if not mo:
        raise ValueError("not a valid version string")
    return mo.groups()


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        raise SystemExit("usage: vercmp VER1 VER2")
    try:
        evr_a = str_to_evr(sys.argv[1].strip())
        evr_b = str_to_evr(sys.argv[2].strip())
        result = rpm.labelCompare(evr_a, evr_b)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise SystemExit("Problem converting or comparing versions: %s %s" % (
            type(exc).__name__, exc))
    print (result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```